# MUI CSS flashes on page load with NextJs 13, MUI 5 and React 18

Tags: next.js, material-ui, emotion

After upgrading to NextJs 13 and MUI 5, my website has a CSS flash on first page load. I run the static NextJs export: `npm run build && npm run export`. I can DM the website URL on request.

What I find confusing is the output of `<style data-emotion="css ">` in the website head section:

```html
<style data-emotion="css "></style>
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/css/72e8bb7ac2b40e6f.css" as="style" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/css/72e8bb7ac2b40e6f.css" data-n-p="" /><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript>
<script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js"></script>
<script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-129f2f716ef4a6e9.js" defer=""></script>
...
```

My packages:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "material-ui-popup-state": "^5.0.4",
    "next": "^13.1.1",
    "node-html-parser": "^6.1.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-share": "^4.4.1",
    "styled-jsx": "^5.1.1",
    "tss-react": "^4.5.2"
  }
```

_document.js:

```js
class AppDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang={
        this?.props?.__NEXT_DATA__?.props?.pageProps?.locale || 'en'
      }>
        <Head>
          <meta name="emotion-insertion-point" content="" />
          {this.props.emotionStyleTags}
        </Head>
        <body style={{ margin: 0 }}>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
        <script src='/analytics.js' />
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

// This is to make Next.js work with MaterialUI
// https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js
// https://blog.logrocket.com/getting-started-with-mui-and-next-js/
AppDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {

  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage
  const cache = createEmotionCache()
  const { extractCriticalToChunks } = createEmotionServer(cache)

  originalRenderPage({
    enhanceApp: (App) =>
      function EnhanceApp(props) {
        return <App emotionCache={cache} {...props} />
      },
  })

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
  const emotionStyles = extractCriticalToChunks(initialProps.html)
  const emotionStyleTags = emotionStyles.styles.map((style) => (
    <style
      data-emotion={`${style.key} ${style.ids.join(" ")}`}
      key={style.key}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: style.css }}
    />
  ))

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    emotionStyleTags,
    locale: ctx.query.locale
  }
}

export default AppDocument
```

_app.js:

```js
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react"

import createEmotionCache from "../lib/mui/createEmotionCache"
import theme from '../config/material-ui/theme'

const clientSideEmotionCache = createEmotionCache()

export default function App({
  Component,
  pageProps,
  cache = clientSideEmotionCache
}) {
  return (
    <CacheProvider value={cache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  )
}
```

I looked into many issues in the MUI repo as well as on Stackoverflow but all the solutions there either refer to older MUI or React versions or are marked as fixed but I can't fix the CSS flash with MUI 5 and Next 13. The flash wasn't there with @material version 4 and Next 12.

Comment: Looks like the MUI styles are not inserted server side but only in the browser. is there a way to render all MUI styles server side with Next 13?